# Unit testing the views in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

How to do unit testing of the controller's function which returns a view. Here, is my controller function

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   $data = Data::all();
   return view('index',[
       'data' => $data
   ]);
}
```

Here is test code

```
public function testIndex()
{
   $response = $this->withoutMiddleware();

   $response = $this->get('/user');

   $response->assertSuccessful();
}
```

I tried this

```
public function testIndex()
{
   $response = $this->withoutMiddleware();

   $response = $this->get('/user');

   $response = $this->assertContains('data', $response->content());

   $response->assertSuccessful();
}
```

which shows error of

> Error: Call to a member function assertSuccessful() on null

Any idea, How to write a test case for my index controller function?

Answer (score 1):

You reassigned $response in your first assert. No need to do that

I don't know what assertContains returns off the top of my head, but I bet it's not $this.

Honestly, I don't know why the sample has you assigning anything to $response in the first place except the response from an HTTP query.

```
public function testIndex()
{
   $this->withoutMiddleware();
   $response = $this->get('/user');
   $this->assertContains('data', $response->content());
   $response->assertSuccessful();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use too

```
$response->assertSeeText('data');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#assert-see-text

Comment: $response is null. How can the OP invokes assertSeeText on null object ?

Comment: Remove assigment from previous line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$this->get('/user')->assertViewHas('data');
```